# How to insert type when join 2 table with scd informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have 2 source tables:

```
table A:                 table B:

A_id || A_code           B_id || B_code 
-----  -------           -----  ------- 
2          t2            1      t1
3          t3            2      t2
4          t4            3      t3
```

I want to join 2 table use *Slowly change dimension*

```
target table:

tgt_id || tgt_code || is_table A || is_table B
-----  ------------   -----------   ----------- 
1          t1         0              x 
2          t2         x              x   
3          t3         x              x
4          t4         x              0
```

I can't check type 'is_table A ' and 'is_table B' when join table.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. What do you mean by `I can't check type 'is_table A ' and 'is_table B' when join table`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to do a full outer join (in SQ or Joiner) on A_id=B_id. Then you can derive the target fields in an expression transformation by doing some null checking as follows:

tgt_id: `IIF(ISNULL(A_id),B_id, A_id)`

tgt_code: `IIF(ISNULL(A_code), B_code, A_code)`

is_table_A: `IIF(ISNULL(A_id),'0','x')`

is_table_B: `IIF(ISULL(B_id), '0', 'x')`